# enquire.js: Check query on page load, then destroy handler

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries, conditional-compilation, enquire.js

I am experimenting with conditional stylesheet loading.

I have multiple elements with multiple breakpoints. For each element and each breakpoint I have created a seperate stylesheet. For example:

- `navi-00em-30em.css`: one column navigation
- `navi-30em-60em.css`: two column navigation
- `navi-60em-inf.css`: inline navigation
- `gal-00em-40em.css`: one column gallery
- `gal-40em-70em.css`: two column gallery
- `gal-70em-inf.css`: four column gallery

and so on…

I added these stylesheets to my head-section by using media queries. I defined them to only load in a specific range of width, for example the stylesheet for the two column navigation had these media attributes:
`screen and (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 59.999999em)`.

This technique of course causes many ugly HTTP Requests which leads to lower performance.
So I had the idea to detect the screen size via javascript on page load and then load a custom merged CSS file. In our case there would be 5 different files. For example if the screen size would be 50em on page load, `gal-40em-70em.css` and `navi-30em-60em` would be merged and appended to the head section. After that the stylesheets which were *not* merged would be appended to the head section with the obvious media attributes.

How can I do that?

### One approach

As I am using enquire.js on the site anyway, I think it is clever to use that script. One possible solution could be (untested!):

```
query1 = "screen and (max-width: 29.999999em)",
query2 = "screen and (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 39.999999em)",
query3 = "screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width: 59.999999em)",
query4 = "screen and (min-width: 60em) and (max-width: 69.999999em)",
query5 = "screen and (min-width: 70em)";
handler1 = {
  match : function() {
    loadCSS('css/merge.php?q=00em-30em'); 
    enquire
      .unregister( query1, [ handler1,
                             handler2,
                             handler3,
                             handler4,
                             handler5
                           ])
      .unregister( query2, [ … ])
      .unregister( query3, [ … ])
      .unregister( query4, [ … ])
      .unregister( query5, [ … ]);
    }
};
handler2 = {
  match : function() {
    loadCSS('css/merge.php?q=30em-40em'); 
    enquire
      .unregister( … ) …;
    }
};
/* and so on */
enquire.register(query1, handler1);
enquire.register(query2, handler2);
enquire.register(query3, handler3);
enquire.register(query4, handler4);
enquire.register(query5, handler5);
```

As you can see this is not very slim and I am also not sure if you can nest enquire handlers like I did in my code. Isn't there an easier method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a [tool](http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/) which does this already.